# Why does this program not print anything?

Tags: html, parsing, go

I'm trying to use Go to parse html. I would like to print the html to the terminal and I don't understand why this doesn't print anything:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"

        "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
        r, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
        if err != nil {
                log.Panicln(err)
        }

        defer func() {
                err := r.Body.Close()
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                }
        }()

        node, err := html.Parse(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
                log.Panicln(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(node.Data)
}
```

I know there are different ways to print the html, but I don't understand why this in particular never prints anything no matter what website I use. Is this intended behavior?

Docs:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html#Node

https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/html/node.go#L38

Comment: Try inspecting the content of 'node'. See what type it is, etc. [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew) can help with this. I suspect node.Data contains nothing, and probably for good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a tree of the HTML. Upper level is empty.
For example if you need parse all url from html:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"

        "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
        r, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
        if err != nil {
                log.Panicln(err)
        }

        defer func() {
                err := r.Body.Close()
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                }
        }()

        node, err := html.Parse(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
                log.Panicln(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(node.Data)

        var f func(*html.Node)
        f = func(n *html.Node) {
            if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
                for _, a := range n.Attr {
                    if a.Key == "href" {
                        fmt.Println(a.Val)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
                f(c)
            }
        }
        f(node)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because html.Parse returns a tree of connected nodes. And the root node is of type "document" which has no data inside of it.

Simplistic example of how to walk the tree:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "strings"

)

func nodeTypeAsString(nodeType html.NodeType) string{
    switch(nodeType){
    case html.ErrorNode : return "ErrorNode"
    case html.TextNode : return "TextNode"
    case html.DocumentNode : return "DocumentNode"
    case html.ElementNode : return "ElementNode"
    case html.CommentNode : return "CommentNode"
    case html.DoctypeNode: return  "DoctypeNode"
    }
    return "UNKNOWN"
}

func main() {
    s := "<html><body><p>Some content</p></body></html>"
    node, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // Root node
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
    // Step deeper
    node = node.FirstChild
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
    // Step deeper
    node = node.FirstChild
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
    // Step over to sibling
    node = node.NextSibling
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
    // Step deeper
    node = node.FirstChild
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
    // Step deeper
    node = node.FirstChild
    fmt.Printf("NodeType=%s Data=%s\n",nodeTypeAsString(node.Type),node.Data)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
NodeType=DocumentNode Data=
NodeType=ElementNode Data=html
NodeType=ElementNode Data=head
NodeType=ElementNode Data=body
NodeType=ElementNode Data=p
NodeType=TextNode Data=Some content
```